# How do we add -webkit-transform property in css in js?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-in-js

```
.underline {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2px;
  left: 50px;
  margin-top: -4px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 185px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0, 1);
  transform: scale(0, 1);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  width: 202px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/xayaraj/pen/amzydG

I am using CSS in JS for my React application and I was wondering how we can put properties such as `-webkit-transition` in our css in js.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
    icon: {
        padding: '.2rem .2rem',
        fontSize: '12px'
    },
    li: {
        display: 'block',
        font: 'bold 6px/12px sans-serif',
        padding: '5px 15px',
        textAlign: 'center',
        textDecoration: 'none',
        float: 'left',
    },
}
```

The code above is me using CSS in JS, I am wondering how I can add the underline class and add the `-webkit-transform` property.

Comment: `transform` has been supported without prefixes for the last 8 years (almost 10 years support in Chrome browser). Are you sure you need to include it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just get rid of the dashes and append your property in camelCase.

change

```
-webkit-transition
```

to

```
webkitTransition
```

This applies to all vendor prefixes.